# using Intelligencia.UrlRewriter to has fake subdomains

Tags: asp.net, regex

I'm trying to to use "Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" to rewrite url to a page with certain query string to subdomain

For example I want to rewite "http://www.silahsahibi.com/subengine.aspx?u=alussilah" to "http://alussilah.silahsahibi.com/"

and that is my "rewriter" tag at web.config file

```
<rewriter>
  <unless header="HTTP_HOST" match="^((www)\.)?silahsahibi.(.+)$">
  <if header="HTTP_HOST" match="^(.*)\.silahsahibi\.([^/]+)$">
    <set property="subdomain" value="$1" />
    <!--<set property="category" value="$2" />
    <rewrite url="^/(\?(.+))?$\?(.+)" to="/SubEngine.aspx?u=${subdomain}&amp;c=${category}" processing="stop"/>-->
    <rewrite url="^/(\?(.+))?$" to="/SubEngine.aspx?u=${subdomain}" processing="stop" />
  </if>
</unless>
</rewriter>
```

but that doesn't work.

I'm not familiar with regex, so could anyone help me with that?

Comment: "but that doesn't work"... What happens? What results are you getting?

Comment: The web.config file is in accordance with your example...

Comment: thank you for your reply, I found that fake subdomains need some dns settings to work fine, but I don't know what exactly should I do.

this example works fine with another website and when I asked its owner he told me that his developer done some dns settings

Answer (score 0):

Change this part:

```
<rewrite url="^/(\?(.+))?$" to="/SubEngine.aspx?u=${subdomain}" processing="stop" />
```

It should be

```
<rewrite url="/(\?(.+))?$" to="/SubEngine.aspx?u=${subdomain}" processing="stop" />
```